# kGetting error while creating Znode with TTL value in zookeeper

Tags: go, apache-zookeeper

```
import (    
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "github.com/go-zookeeper/zk"
)
func ConnectZK() (*zk.Conn, error) {
    zkServers := []string{"localhost:2181"}
    c, _, err := zk.Connect(zkServers, time.Second*10)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return c, nil
}
func CreateZNode(partnerid string, psatktid string) {
    c, err := ConnectZK()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Before CreateTTL " + c.State().String())
    defer c.Close()
    zNodePath := "/abc_dedup/" + partnerid + "-" + psatktid

    duration := time.Duration(10 * time.Second)

    // below line's code is working & creating Znode without TTL perfectly
    zNode, err := c.Create(zNodePath, []byte("value"+"_"+psatktid), int32(zk.FlagTTL), zk.WorldACL(zk.PermAll))

    //below line's code is throwing an error as an "invalid argument", coming from internal functions attached in pic
    zNode, err = c.CreateTTL(zNodePath, []byte("value"+"_"+psatktid), int32(zk.FlagTTL), zk.WorldACL(zk.PermAll), duration)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(zNode)
}
```

I am trying to create zookeeper zNode with TTL in golang by using "github.com/go-zookeeper/zk" lib.

In my code getting following error, however I am able to create normal Znode with same code, only getting error for TTL nodes.

[image: Error]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text.

Comment: Voker meant [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/720999)–please read it carefully. As to your question: what is the code on your pic? It looks like the code of the `github.com/go-zookeeper/zk` library; am I correct? If so, this is not really interesting. Can you instead show–in plain textual form–your code that works and the same code which does not? (If you have no idea how to format the code, [here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)).

Comment: Yes, in the pic the code is for github.com/go-zookeeper/zk, as error is coming from an inside function, hence highlighted that.

Comment: Added line of code which is working without TTL in same function like below

// below line's code is working & creating Znode without TTL perfectly
    zNode, err := c.Create(zNodePath, []byte("value"+"_"+psatktid), int32(zk.FlagTTL), zk.WorldACL(zk.PermAll))

Comment: Can someone help here

Answer (score 0):

I got the same errors and fixed with using `zk.FlagTTL|zk.FlagEphemeral` instead of `zk.FlagTTL` only.

You can try something like this:

```
zNode, err = c.CreateTTL(zNodePath, []byte("value"+"_"+psatktid), zk.FlagTTL|zk.FlagEphemeral, zk.WorldACL(zk.PermAll), duration)
```

Here is my similar question：
[Using go-zookeeper api to create TTL Node always shows invalid arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77811413/using-go-zookeeper-api-to-create-ttl-node-always-shows-invalid-arguments)

Note that starting from 3.5.3, Zookeeper supports the creation of Time-To-Live (TTL) nodes. So Make sure the Zookeeper server version is 3.5.3 or later.

If the version is not the issue, we may need manually add these 2 setting and restart the Zookeeper server.

```
znode.container.checkIntervalMs=60000 
znode.container.maxPerMinute=10000
```

These configurations enable the scheduling of the removal operation for container nodes and TTL nodes in Zookeeper. The first one controls the interval between each run of the removal operation in milliseconds, and the default value is 60000 milliseconds (or 1 minute). The second one controls how many nodes at maximum can be removed per minute.